# ¿Como pasar datos de un controlador a script ajax en Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Estoy haciendo pruebas en jquery (pues soy algo novato) y quiero pasar un dato desde un controlador a un script ajax, este codigo actualmente me da un **error POST 500 (Internal Server Error)**

El dato que quiero obtener es el campo quantity del modelo Spares ($pares->quantity)

Dejo los respectivos codigos:

Ruta

```
Route::post('select-ajax', ['as'=>'select-ajax','uses'=>'MaintenanceController@selectAjax']);
```

Controlador

```
public function selectAjax(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $spares = DB::table('spares')->where('spare_id',$request->spare_id)->pluck("name","id","quantity")->all();
            return Response::json($spares);
        }


    }
```

Script de la vista

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                                $('select').change(function(){
                                    var spare_id = $(this).val();
                                    var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "<?php echo route('select-ajax') ?>",
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        data: {spare_id:spare_id, _token:token},
                                        success: function(data) {
                                            alert("hola"); //aqui deseo obtener el dato $spares->quantity
                                        }
                                    });
                            });

                        });
```

**EDIT:**

Cambios que se realizaron para llegar a la solución del problema:

En el controlador

```
$spares = DB::table('spares')->where('id',$request->spare_id)->first(); // se cambio spare_id por id, se  elimino metodo pluck y se cambio metodo all() por first()
return response()->json($spares); //se cambio Response:: por response ()->
```

En el script pude obtener el dato con:

```
console.log(data.quantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como estás regresando todos los registros tendrías que ir recorriendo uno por uno:

```
$.each(data, function(i, elemento){ //Recorres los registros que te devuelve
   console.log(elemento.quantity); //Aquí está el atributo "quantity" de cada registro
});
```

En tu ajax especifica el tipo de dato que necesitas:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Para tu consulta sugeriría que usaras Eloquent, si estás usando el facade `DB` asegúrate de incluirlo en tu clase.

```
use DB;
```

O bien, también puedes acceder directamente a él sin incluirlo en la clase:

```
\DB::table('spares')->where('spare_id',$request->spare_id)->pluck("name","id","quantity")->all();
```

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, en vez del all() deberia usar first() ya que es solo un registro el que encontrara.

En el controlador tengo agregado:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Como es un solo registro puse esto en el script:
console.log(spares.quantity);
pero me sigue mandando 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @tabano No es necesario que pongas toda la ruta en este caso de ese facade ya que tiene un alias, con usar `use DB;` basta, ¿Qué te responde la petición?, lo puedes ver en la pestaña de "respuesta" o "vista previa" de tu consola.

Comment: Imagino te refieres a la consola del Chrome, en la pestaña Sources me destaca la siguiente linea del script: `$.ajax({` (que es en el archivo de vista)

Comment: @tabano ¿Podrías agregar captura de pantalla de eso en tu pregunta?

Comment: Acabo de agregar dos capturas referentes al error

Comment: @tabano Ya vi lo que te señala, pero me refería a lo que te regresa la petición ajax, lo puedes consultar, en la pestaña network y activas el filtro de `XHR` para ver peticiones al servidor.

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'spare_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `name`, `id` from `spares` where `spare_id` = 3)",

Comment: @tabano Tu error es ese, la columna `spare_id` no existe en tu tabla `spares`.

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar, ya que el campo era "id", ahora manda error por lo siguiente message": "Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Response' not found",

Comment: @tabano Sí, lo que pasa es que no tienes la clase importada, pero en vez de usar la clase `Response` puedes usar la función "response" de esta manera: `return response()->json($spares);`.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora no me esta dando ningun error, logro ver el alert, ahora respecto a ver el dato pasado del controlador a la vista mediante la consola con: `console.log(data.quantity);` me sale `undefined` en la consola, se te ocurre que puede ser? (muchas gracias por toda la ayuda brindada hasta ahora)

Comment: A pesar de recibir el undefined por consola, me di cuenta que en la pestaña respuesta si me devuelve un dato, pero en este caso corresponde a la columna "name", no "quantity".
Al aplicar `console.log(data.quantity);` en el script me di cuenta que toma el primer valor segun lo definido aqui en el controlador `->pluck("name","id","quantity")`, si intercambio "name" por "quantity" al primer lugar ahi si obtengo como respuesta ajax el valor del campo quantity, aun asi porque la consola me devuelve "undefined" ?

Comment: @tabano Lo que pasa es que `pluck()` lo que hace es que te devuelve todos los valores dadas las columnas o "llaves" que le envías por parámetros, es decir, si en un registro tienes la columna `name` y es igual a `Juan`, `id` es igual a 2 y quantity es igual a 3, pluck se encargará de obtener sólo los valores, es decir, "Juan, 2, 3", si aplicas el método `all()`  después de `pluck()` te devolverá un `Array['Juan', 2, 3]` y si aplicas first, te devolverá: `'Juan'`;

Comment: @tabano Sugiero que omitas el `pluck()`, a menos que de plano no quieras incluir alguna información específica de alguna columna de tu tabla.

Comment: Efectivamente luego de resolver los errores, el metodo pluck() era el problema, ahora entiendo como funciona realmente. Luego de eliminarlo puedo obtener el dato que quiero, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.